# Upload filesize limit in CodeIgniter seems to be ignored

Tags: php, codeigniter, file-upload, codeigniter-2

I am working on a CodeIgniter project that involves file uploads. When I try to upload a file 2.2MB (default upload size limit in CI is 2MB = 2048KB) it works with no problem. But when I try something bigger (21.5MB) it returns:

> [msg] => You did not select a file to upload"

I changed the max_size parameter to both "0" and "204800" (200MB in KB), but still nothing works. You will say to check my php.ini file, but I already did and the max_upload_size directive is set to 200M, which also `phpinfo()` confirms.

So, please tell me, what am I doing wrong and which is the right way to do it?

Comment: What does the `print_r($_FILES)` say?

Comment: PROBLEM SOLVED!!! The post_max_size variable should be also set to 200M. The question may be deleted now :)

Comment: @emilavramov you can delete by yourself

Comment: @Emil, it is better to self-answer below so that it might help someone else in the future.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using POST to upload your files, you may also want to change your htaccess file.

`php_value upload_max_filesize 2M`